# Bulk Upload to sonatype nexus3

Tags: nuget, nexus, nuget-server

We currently have a nuget server with a klondike frontend, this stores all of the packages in a simple folder.

We want to upload all of our packages to a new nexus3 server.

How would I go about this ?

Can I just copy the files to folder ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this at current time would be to script something out via powershell/some other Windows sorcery that loops through the packages and publishes them to Nexus Repository 3. If you do so, let me know, we can add whatever you come up with to http://exchange.sonatype.com/ to help out other users.